# Why are humans mostly right-handed?

Tags: human-biology, brain

Most sources I've seen say that about 90% of humans are right handed, and 10% are left handed. Why is this?

My only guess would be that it has something to do with different parts of the brain developing differently and causing right or left "handedness", but this is coming from my very little knowledge of the brain.

Furthermore, about 2/3 of people are right eye dominant, and more people are right ear dominant than left ear dominant.

*Why the right side?!?*